# How to change the axis line size in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the size and color of the right y axis and the top x axis of my diagramm q.
axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 1.0) changes only my left y axis and bottom x axis. I also tried axis.line.y.right = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 1.0) but it doesn´t work.
Do you have any ideas?

[image: my plot]

```
> # additional packages
    > #install.packages("ggthemes")
    > 
    > usePackage("data.table")
    > usePackage("ggplot2")
    > 
    > # load packages
    > library(data.table)
    > library(ggplot2)
    > library(ggthemes)
    > 
    > 
    > results <- fread("Thiols_Data_5.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
    > 
    > str(results)
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ Yeast: chr  "AWRI Ref" "AWRI tna" "ATF 1" "ATF 2" ...
     $ SHA  : int  36 173 382 3219 686 45
     $ SHAsd: int  15 81 56 217 56 17
     $ SH   : int  387 330 4623 3265 4123 701
     $ SHsd : int  19 100 266 86 646 61
     - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
    > 
    > df <- data.frame(results)
    > 
    > str(df)
    'data.frame':   6 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ Yeast: chr  "AWRI Ref" "AWRI tna" "ATF 1" "ATF 2" ...
     $ SHA  : int  36 173 382 3219 686 45
     $ SHAsd: int  15 81 56 217 56 17
     $ SH   : int  387 330 4623 3265 4123 701
     $ SHsd : int  19 100 266 86 646 61
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > # Manually set factor levels of 'Yeast' column to plot in a logical order.
    > df$Yeast = factor(df$Yeast, 
    +                   levels=c("AWRI Ref", "ATF 1", "ATF 2", "AWRI tna", "ATF 1 tna", "ATF 2 tna"),
    +                   labels=c("AWRI1631\n[REF]", "AWRI1631\n[ATF1]", "AWRI1631\n[ATF2]", "AWRI1631\n[tnaA]", "AWRI1631\n[tnaA_ATF1]", "AWRI1631\n[tnaA_ATF2]")) 
    > 
    > p= ggplot( df ,aes( Yeast, SH, fill=Yeast )) +
    +     geom_bar( stat="identity",
    +               colour="black", size=0.7, 
    +               width=0.3 
    +     ) + 
    +     scale_fill_manual(values= c("AWRI1631\n[REF]"="#0073C299", "AWRI1631\n[ATF1]"="#EFC00099", "AWRI1631\n[ATF2]"="#86868699", "AWRI1631\n[tnaA]" ="#CD534C99", "AWRI1631\n[tnaA_ATF1]"="#7AA6DC99", "AWRI1631\n[tnaA_ATF2]"="#003C6799"),
    +                       labels= c("AWRI1631[REF]", "AWRI1631[ATF1]", "AWRI1631[ATF2]", "AWRI1631[tnaA]", "AWRI1631[tnaA_ATF1]", "AWRI1631[tnaA_ATF2]"))+ 
    +     geom_errorbar( aes(ymin=SH-SHsd, ymax=SH+SHsd), width=.1 , position = "dodge", size=0.7) + 
    +     scale_y_continuous(name="concentration in ng/L\n", 
    +                        expand=c(0,0), 
    +                        limits=c(0,5000) 
    +     )+ 
    +     xlab("\nYeast")+ 
    +     theme_bw()       
    > 
    > #without background lines
    > q=p+theme_few(base_size = 15)+ 
    +     theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 1.0), 
    +           axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"), 
    +           axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black"), 
    +           axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "pt")      
    +     ) 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > ggsave("Thiols_5.png", plot=q, width=11.5, height=6.5, dpi=400)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looking at x and y axis, but at the panel border.

User Stefan suggested to include how to mirror your x / y axis in case this is what you also wanted. - Just delete the two last lines of code if this is *not* what you want :)

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_blank() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(size = 3)) +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Maybe you should add to your answer how to add a dup_axis. (:

Comment: @stefan I didn't see this was part of the OP's question.. ?

Comment: Yeah. Probably you are right. Just meant in case that ... Best S.

Comment: @stefan I think you might be right too :D have included that now. Let's see what the OP actually wanted